# Javascript global value remained NULL after attempting to change it via function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the global variable in javascript after it picks up changes in a drop down list.

Below is the HTML:

```
<select class='dropdown' id='selection' onChange='checkyo()'>
 <option value="is_revenue">Revenue</option>
 <option value="is_costofrevenue">Cost of Revenue</option>
</select>
```

Below is the javascript:

```
var isSelected = {}; //global variable

checkyo = function() {
  chosen = document.getElementById("selection").value;
  isSelected = chosen;
};

alert(isSelected);  //check the updated value
```

I am expecting the value of isSelected to be either is_revenue or is_costofrevenue depending on the drop down list selected by the user but then my alert is showing an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onchange event only fires when the dropdown box element is changed.  The alert is currently outside of that handler.  Move the alert inside of the checkyo() function.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GLyq/).

HTML

```
<select class='dropdown' id='selection' onChange='checkyo()'>
 <option value="is_revenue">Revenue</option>
 <option value="is_costofrevenue">Cost of Revenue</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
var isSelected = {}; //global variable

checkyo = function() {
  chosen = document.getElementById("selection").value;
  isSelected = chosen;
  alert(isSelected);  //check the updated value
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your alert is issued *before* anything changes the select box's value. Move the alert *into* the `onchange` handler (`checkyo`). Also ensure that your code runs *after* the element exists (the simplest way is to put the `script` tag at the end of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag).

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/gepucira/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<select class='dropdown' id='selection' onChange='checkyo()'>
 <option value="is_revenue">Revenue</option>
 <option value="is_costofrevenue">Cost of Revenue</option>
</select>
  <script>
    var isSelected = {}; //global variable

    checkyo = function() {
      chosen = document.getElementById("selection").value;
      isSelected = chosen;

      alert(isSelected);  //check the updated value
    };

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, I am asking the wrong question; my bad, I shall accept your answer and inquire a fresh one. Thanks!